# Use of Nmap ssl/http md5 and SHA1 hashes

Tags: hash, linux, penetration-test, nmap

I have below stated result on of the system by map:

```
443/tcp  open   ssl/http    Apache httpd 2.0.52 ((CentOS))
| http-methods: GET HEAD POST OPTIONS TRACE
| Potentially risky methods: TRACE
|_See http://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/http-methods.html
| http-robots.txt: 2 disallowed entries 
|_/internal/  /tmp/ 
|_http-title: Site doesn't have a title (text/html; charset=UTF-8).
| ssl-cert: Subject: commonName=localhost.localdomain/organizationName=SomeOrganization/stateOrProvinceName=SomeState/countryName=--/emailAddress=root@localhost.localdomain/localityName=SomeCity/organizationalUnitName=SomeOrganizationalUnit
| Issuer: commonName=localhost.localdomain/organizationName=SomeOrganization/stateOrProvinceName=SomeState/countryName=--/emailAddress=root@localhost.localdomain/localityName=SomeCity/organizationalUnitName=SomeOrganizationalUnit
| Public Key type: rsa
| Public Key bits: 1024
| Not valid before: 2009-09-16T14:03:22+00:00
| Not valid after:  2010-09-16T14:03:22+00:00
| MD5:   1a3c xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx
| SHA-1: ef51 xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx
| -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
| .............some value.................
|_-----END CERTIFICATE-----
|_ssl-date: 2015-08-12T18:50:09+00:00; -55s from local time.
| sslv2: 
|   SSLv2 supported
|   ciphers: 
|     SSL2_DES_192_EDE3_CBC_WITH_MD5
|     SSL2_RC2_CBC_128_CBC_WITH_MD5
|     SSL2_RC4_128_WITH_MD5
|     SSL2_RC4_64_WITH_MD5
|     SSL2_DES_64_CBC_WITH_MD5
|     SSL2_RC2_CBC_128_CBC_WITH_MD5
|_    SSL2_RC4_128_EXPORT40_WITH_MD5
```

In a penetration test how can I use this value?I need to know how can i use those MD5 or SHA-1 hashes or other ciphers.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple pieces of information in this output which could be of use to a security/penetration tester.

- Version of Apache used and the Operating system involved.  This version of Apache has a number of [known security issues](http://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-45/product_id-66/version_id-15944/Apache-Http-Server-2.0.52.html), so as a tester you could research those to understand whether they are exploitable.
- The two robots.txt entries (/internal/ and /tmp/) would be interesting as a tester.  Companies usually places those to denote areas that they don't want spidered, which are generally internal administration areas or similar.  Of course those areas are also interesting to attackers.  So I would always open a browser and visit those URLs to see if they are potential points of attack.
- The use of SSLv2 and weak ciphers.  Definitely one for a report as a security tester as those are very old and weak.  Whether in reality you'd attack those on a test is another matter. If you can get a MITM position then it might be possible to downgrade a connection and attempt to crack the encryption, but realistically if you can MITM the connection just use [sslstrip](http://www.thoughtcrime.org/software/sslstrip/) and get rid of it all together.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your specific questions around SHA1 and weak cipher suites:

- SHA1 is considered weak signing algorithm now. Great long run down can be read here. Basic googling can help beyond this: https://konklone.com/post/why-google-is-hurrying-the-web-to-kill-sha-1 *Nmap example does not confirm nor contain a certificate showing SHA1 weakness.
- Weak cipher suites can be susceptible to a number of attacks which all depend on the implementation. A significant amount of proper references to papers, attacks, and nested proof of concepts can be found in this paper: https://www.ssllabs.com/downloads/SSL_TLS_Deployment_Best_Practices.pdf.

Comment: The MD5 and SHA-1 hashes in that output are certificate fingerprints, not signing algorithms. They are calculated by Nmap and displayed regardless of what hash function was used in the certificate signature.

Comment: Thanks for the note, guess I took the question a bit too literally since SHA1 signed certs are weak but in this instance are not in question. Clarified answer with an edit.